# Share the variable between nodeJs and angularJS using

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am new to Node/Angular and trying to get a variable into angular's `$scope`.

Here is what I am doing.

I have this line in app.js (node server side scr):

`app.get('/homepage', login.redirectToHomepage);`

The redirectToHomepage is defined as follows in one of my node modules:

`function redirectToHomePage (req, res) {
     ...
     res.render("homepage",{data: results[0]});
     ...
}`

homepage.html
(This  works as expected and I see the value being substituted)

`<li><a href="/about" style="color:#FFFFFF"> <%=data.email%> </a></li>`

The controller for homepage.html is : mainCtrl

I want to be able to access the variable "data" in mainCtrl so that I can do the below:

`<li><a href="/about" style="color:#FFFFFF"> {{data.email}} </a></li>`

I have tried :

`<div> ng-controller=“mainCtrl” ng-init="data= #{JSON.stringify(data)}”>`

If I use JSON.stringify I get parse errors in browser console. 
Ref: [Pass Variables to Angular from Server](http://www.mircozeiss.com/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-from-a-server-to-angular/)

What should I write in mainCtrl to make the above line work? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation with any view renderer like ejs, jade, JSP ( for java for that matter).
Two ways to get the data from server to front end :

1. Make an ajax call and get the response assigned to the concerned veriable.
2. in html page write `<script>var data = <%=data.email%>;</script>`, while in another js file ( that should be loaded anywhere after the prescribed snipped), you may easily assign this global data veriable to any scope veriable like this : `$scope.dataFromServer = data;`